# React-Bootstrap Carousel occasionally gets stuck on the second image

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

My React-Bootstrap Carousel occasionally sticks on the second image for an extended duration even though I have an interval set of `{1500}`.

This happens no matter what image I use there.  Any ideas?

```js
function Work() {

  return (
    <Carousel fade indicators={false} controls={false} >

       {/* provides brief period with no image. */}
       <Carousel.Item interval={200}></Carousel.Item>

      <Carousel.Item interval={1500}>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src={news} alt="News Flash" />
      </Carousel.Item>

      <Carousel.Item interval={5000}>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={newsBlur}
          alt="News Flash blurred"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption style={styles.carouselCaption}>
          <h3>
            News Flash gathers news based on the user's
            news category preferences.
          </h3>
          <h3>
            <a
              href="https://github.com/Xr7TSi/News-Flash"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              style={styles.buttonPrimary}
            >
              <h5>See the repo</h5>
            </a>
          </h3>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you hover your mouse over the image while it is being displayed which will cause your Carousel to stick on that image regardless of the interval. Once you move your mouse away then the Carousel will shift to the next image.

Comment: It looks like that was it!  I've added pause={false} to the carousel.  Thanks!